# Performance Analysis of Node.JS application

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I have developed an application on Node.JS and stress tested it with JMeter. I have provided the throughput below which I dont understand.

Case 1:- For normal single node application:
1000 concurrent users X 1000 request made in 1 second -> throughput is 65,885 request/minute
(total 1000000 requests)
Case 2:-For application with a cluster of 4 nodes:
1000 concurrent users X 1000 request made in 1 second -> throughput is 32,215 request/minute
(total 1000000 requests)

P.S.: Both the tests are made on same 4-core machine. Cluster of 4 nodes is created using 'cluster' npm and there is no communication between any cluster nodes. As Node.JS is not multithreaded, No context switching among threads or processes, ideally if Case 1 process 4 request in 1 second, Case 2 should process 1 request in 1 second. I know this case is not possible in a multithreaded application. I thought Node.JS will provide some 4X throughput in Case 2 than Case 1, but right now it provided only 2X in my test.

Can anyone explain the rational behind it? Is it because all the worker nodes listening to the same port? or Inbuilt load-balancing among worker nodes is naive or something else?